# 3rd Party dll in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a third party dll that I am trying to reference in my Silverlight project. I am able to use this dll and reference it in a test WPF application. Trying to reference this same dll in my silverlight application is not working. I am using the automationFactory class to get a handle on the dll but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

```
dynamic btApp = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("BarTender.Application");
```

By putting Bartender.Application as the argument in the CreateObject method I am able to get a handle on a dll, but Im afraid it is not the correct dll. How do I reference a particular dll that I need to use.

---

Code

```
dynamic btApp = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("BarTender.Application"); 
//dynamic btMessages = null; 
dynamic btFormat = btApp.Formats.Open("c:\\Temp/Format1.btw", false, "");
btFormat.SetNamedSubStringValue("testing", barcodeValue); 
btFormat.Print("Job1");
btFormat.Close(2);
```

Comment: I'll make a comment: `BarTender` needs to be an application that is installed.

Comment: Question: What do you want from this 3rd party dll? Do you plan on packaging this ddl with your silverlight project or are you assuming it will be on the user system?

Comment: i want to be able to use their print method..here is my code..dynamic btApp = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("BarTender.Application");
                //dynamic btMessages = null;

                dynamic btFormat = btApp.Formats.Open("c:\\Temp/Format1.btw", false, "");
                btFormat.SetNamedSubStringValue("testing", barcodeValue);
                btFormat.Print("Job1");

                btFormat.Close(2);

Comment: that btFormat.Print method at the bottom isnt working..I didnt have the right sdk from them...so im trying to reference this new dll that they gave me..but I cant seem to get a handle on it...

Comment: That AutomationFactory.CreateObject doesnt seem to reference the right dll...wondering how i can get a handle on a particular dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is a complete different framework from wpf. You need to get a the dll built for the silverlight runtime.

Reason: WPF is more integrated into windows/.net framework. This Dll may reference system calls. Silverlight has its own framework (very small subset of the .net framework).

---

Silverlight 4:

If shipping the library: This guy explained it [here](http://avcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/silverlight-4-accessing-net-assembly-com-automationfactory/).

---

I do not suggest usint COM integration for this purpose (I see something about `Print()`. Maybe that DLL requires the full .net framework. Not all users of silverlight will have that. Its best if you go WPF.

Comment: Is it not possible to get a handle on a dll then using the AutomationFactory class?

Comment: Crap, I should delete this answer, this is a silverlight 3 answer. Forgot 4 supported COM integration.

Comment: If I do have a dll built for silverlight do I reference it just like I would any other dll in other project?

Comment: Any guidance on this AutomationFactory and how I can get a handle on this dll, if SL4 does indeed do this..

Comment: I'll edit my post, you can use COM integration to reference non silverlight dlls.

Comment: It only works out of browser though, and I think the user must confirm being admin. More about COM integration here: http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures

Comment: I am running OOB...thanks for the link..i will take a look at that now.

Comment: Shawn...thanks for all the help..im going to try what is mentioned in this link..if this works..your the king!...thanks again.